# GraphicsGL External Reference Errors

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am sorry if this has been posted somewhere else or if this is rudamentary but I am having issues troubleshooting build errors I am getting in a C++ project (.exe).

Do you think you can take a look for me, thank you!

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestProject, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>GraphicsGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBindTexture referenced in function "public: class jrc::Error __cdecl jrc::GraphicsGL::init(void)" (?init@GraphicsGL@jrc@@QEAA?AVError@2@XZ)
1>GraphicsGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBlendFunc referenced in function "public: void __cdecl jrc::GraphicsGL::reinit(void)" (?reinit@GraphicsGL@jrc@@QEAAXXZ)
1>GraphicsGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glClear referenced in function "public: void __cdecl jrc::GraphicsGL::flush(float)" (?flush@GraphicsGL@jrc@@QEAAXM@Z)
1>GraphicsGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glClearColor referenced in function "public: void __cdecl jrc::GraphicsGL::flush(float)" (?flush@GraphicsGL@jrc@@QEAAXM@Z)
1>GraphicsGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glDrawArrays referenced in function "public: void __cdecl jrc::GraphicsGL::flush(float)" (?flush@GraphicsGL@jrc@@QEAAXM@Z)
1>GraphicsGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glEnable referenced in function "public: void __cdecl jrc::GraphicsGL::reinit(void)" (?reinit@GraphicsGL@jrc@@QEAAXXZ)
1>GraphicsGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glGenTextures referenced in function "public: class jrc::Error __cdecl jrc::GraphicsGL::init(void)" (?init@GraphicsGL@jrc@@QEAA?AVError@2@XZ)
1>GraphicsGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glPixelStorei referenced in function "public: class jrc::Error __cdecl jrc::GraphicsGL::init(void)" (?init@GraphicsGL@jrc@@QEAA?AVError@2@XZ)
1>GraphicsGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glTexImage2D referenced in function "public: class jrc::Error __cdecl jrc::GraphicsGL::init(void)" (?init@GraphicsGL@jrc@@QEAA?AVError@2@XZ)
1>GraphicsGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glTexParameteri referenced in function "public: class jrc::Error __cdecl jrc::GraphicsGL::init(void)" (?init@GraphicsGL@jrc@@QEAA?AVError@2@XZ)
1>GraphicsGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glTexSubImage2D referenced in function "private: bool __cdecl jrc::GraphicsGL::addfont(char const *,enum jrc::Text::Font,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?addfont@GraphicsGL@jrc@@AEAA_NPEBDW4Font@Text@2@II@Z)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glLoadIdentity referenced in function "public: class jrc::Error __cdecl jrc::Window::initwindow(void)" (?initwindow@Window@jrc@@QEAA?AVError@2@XZ)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glMatrixMode referenced in function "public: class jrc::Error __cdecl jrc::Window::initwindow(void)" (?initwindow@Window@jrc@@QEAA?AVError@2@XZ)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glViewport referenced in function "public: class jrc::Error __cdecl jrc::Window::initwindow(void)" (?initwindow@Window@jrc@@QEAA?AVError@2@XZ)
1>D:\TestProject\x64\Debug\TestProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 14 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "TestProject.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Also I have no idea what that LINK error is referencing. I am using Visual Studio 2017 but I have it set to "Visual Studio 2015 (v140)" for the "Platform Toolset". Running in Debug x64

I am using these libraries:
Graphics: GLFW3, GLEW, FreeType
Audio: Bass

Comment: Without more information the duplicate is best advice to give.

Comment: I added "opengl32.lib" to "Additional Dependencies" in Linker and it fixed everything except the first error. Thanks though...